# Unable to programmatically create a clipping mask in Illustrator with Extendscript

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am having trouble creating a clipping mask in Illustrator using ExtendScript, the problem is that im trying to create it by using compound path item.

In adobe illustrator i can group the compound path item with the background and press "Create new mask" and every thing works, but i cant do it programatically

If i use a path item (not compound path) and the next code:

```
newGroup1.clipped = true;
```

It works, but if i sustitute the path item for a compund path item, it doesnt work.

The code:

```
app.activeDocument.newGroup1.selected = true;
app.executeMenuCommand("makeMask");
```

With simple compound path items, it work, but with complex compound path items i get a message box that said that the paths are so complex and it could affect the preview. After i press ok it works, but this message box does not allow me to do a batch process.

Is there any way to programatically create clipping mask by using complex compound path items??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your setup basically works, the only problem are the message boxes.

However, those can be supressed in a script by setting the app's `userInteractionLevel`:

```js
app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;
```

If you do this, it's usually good practice to save the initial userInteractionLevel at the beginning of the script and then in the end, reset it to its initial value:

```
myUserInteractionLevel = app.userInteractionLevel;
app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;

// then do all your stuff
// and in the end, reset:

app.userInteractionLevel = myUserInteractionLevel;
```